# C++ - Remove or skip quote char in reading a file line by tokenizer

Tags: c++, string, tokenize

I have a csv file that has records like:

> 837478739*"EP"*1*"3FB2B464BD5003B55CA6065E8E040A2A"*"F"*21*15*"NH"*"N"*0**-1*"-1"*0*0**-1*223944*-1*"23"*1*"-1"*"-1"*"78909"*"-1"*"-1"*"-1"*"-1"*"-1"*"-1"*"-1"*"-1"*"-1"*"-1"*"-1"*"-1"*"-1"*"74425"*"26"*"-1"*"-1"*1*1*69*23.58*0*0*0*0*"MC"

The file has lots of records, so I need a fast method to breakdown the line and push_back each of those parts into a vector. The main reason I choose tokenizer is that I heard a lot about its performance. I have a function:

```
void break(){
   //using namespace boost;
   string s = "This is a , test '' file";
   boost::tokenizer<> tok(s);
   vector<string> line;
   for(boost::tokenizer<>::iterator beg=tok.begin();beg!=tok.end();++beg){
       line.push_back(*beg);
   }
   cout << line[3] << "  and  " << line[5] << endl;
}
```

By that I can get each part of the sentence and ignore everything that is not a letter. Does the tokenizer have the ability to read the record that I have and parse them by "*" delimiter and remove the quotes from the string? There won't be any kind of special character between quotes, I just need to remove the quote marks. I tried to read the tokenizer document, but nothing came out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign another TokenizerFunc to your Tokenizer to parse the string differently, the default parses on space and punctuation

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/tokenizer/tokenizerfunction.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex_replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/regex/match_replace/).

"break" is keyword. You shouldn't use it for function name.